# How to make a progress bar in console?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I've done something like this this:

```
#include <thread>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  //...
  std::thread sad_thread(MakeMeFeelSad(), params);
  sad_thread.join();
  //...
  std::thread happy_thread(MakeMeFeelHappy(), params);
  happy_thread.join();
  //...
}
```

Functions `MakeMeFeelSad` and `MakeMeFeelHappy` runs for about 2 mins each, I need to make in cmd something like this: *I'm getting Sad/Happy.....* (while functions are running)- And dots always appear until 5, then they disappear, and appear again. It's like progress bar with the dots. How can I make this ?

ETA: I mean do I need another one thread with callback ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use something like:

```
std::future<void> fut = std::async(std::launch::async, MakeMeFeelSad, params);

std::cout << "I'm getting Sad";
std::chrono::milliseconds span (100);
while (fut.wait_for(span) == std::future_status::timeout)
    std::cout << '.';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create another `thread`, indeed, but it is also possible to use a `condition_variable` object, and loop on the `wait_until` method. You will be able to display your dots in this loop.

See [Timeout for thread.join()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9948420/timeout-for-thread-join)